# How to register a process on Windows task scheduler using c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess, taskscheduler

I'm currently looking for a method to register a process on Windows task scheduler using c++(writing some code).

I have searched some of possible methods on the internet but I could not find any using c/c++.

Using CreateProcess to register a process on task scheduler might be the one solution and I found an example

```
char buf[MAX_PATH] = "cmd /c schtasks.exe /create /sc onlogon /tn \"APP\" /tr \"C:\\SOME_PATH" /rl highest"; 
CreateProcess(NULL, buf, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

However, as there is no explanation I do not wish to use this example.

Can anyone please explain to me what the given example is doing or any other way to register a process on Windows task scheduler?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/aa381911

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the reply. It seems relevant to my question. But there is a problem with it. It registers a process on task scheduler successfully. However, it never actually starts the process although it is scheduled to start on every boot. Do you know how to fix it? I have literally used the example given the only thing I have changed is _wgetenv to _wgetenv_s and I have checked that the calling path is correct. *The error code is 0x41301.

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383604.aspx), that error code is saying that the task is already running. Some [Google search results](https://www.google.no/search?&q=windows+error+code+41301) suggest that you may have to set the "Start in" setting.